# C/C++ multiple pointers?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pointers, handle

Ok so I've been thinking about this for some time, and i can only come up with one solution.
My problem is the following:
-> Im handeling a USB flash
-> I split its size in 3 parts
-> I have 3 threads, each one with a pointer, and the 3 parts are distributed to the tree threads;

Now this is the part that bugs my head:
If i only have one handle handeling the usb and if, for each thread, i set a pointer using the only handle i have, it will be a reall mess.

Theard 1 sets the pointer to 0;

Thread 2 sets the pointer to 100;

Thread 3 sets the pointer to 500;

The pointer will be, for each thread, at 500 because it will be the last place he will be.

I want to make so that every thread starts in a individual place.
I think the only solution to my problem is to have diferent handles for each thread, but i find that solution pretty bad and unpractic.
I would love if someone knows of a better solution to my problem!
Regardless, thanks!

This is the 2 functions im using (hanlde and the pointer):

Pointer:

`DWORD WINAPI SetFilePointer(
  _In_        HANDLE hFile,
  _In_        LONG   lDistanceToMove,
  _Inout_opt_ PLONG  lpDistanceToMoveHigh,
  _In_        DWORD  dwMoveMethod
);`

Handler:

```
    HANDLE WINAPI CreateFile(
      _In_     LPCTSTR               lpFileName,
      _In_     DWORD                 dwDesiredAccess,
  _In_     DWORD                 dwShareMode,
  _In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
  _In_     DWORD                 dwCreationDisposition,
  _In_opt_ HANDLE                hTemplateFile
  _In_     DWORD                 dwFlagsAndAttributes,
);
```

Comment: One Pointer for multiple Threads is always a bad idea. You should create something threadsafe, which holds the pointer and can distribute data to all threads

Comment: But i need to set a pointer for each thread, all in the same file. The "safe" way or the way that i tought about it to have 1 handle for each thread, but that seems un eficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have multiple file pointers to the same file (or rather, same file object). There are few ways around that:

- open same file (device in your case) several times, that will get you independent file objects and each will have its own current position.
- use I/O operations which don't use current position pointers, e.g. async I/O like `WriteFileEx`
- (as a variation on the previous idea) use memory-mapped I/O, i.e. `MapViewOfFile`

Comment: Goddamn how didnt i think about the `MapViewOfFile` xD Yes, in theory that solves my problem of having to make new handles for each thread! Much appreciated!